# How to detect that youtube has finished to play on iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios

How to detect that youtube has finished to play on iphone ? I can't see how since youtube plays in another app or web safari.

But I have seen some apps that can play youtube video one after another so it should be but then how ?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about integrating a movie into your app, (which I believe you'd do by loading the video URI into `MPMoviePlayerController`), you'd listen for `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`.  If you clarify your question though, I may know another method.